# Recipe Compile Error - Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

First time working with ruby and chef.  I have the following code, the last 4 lines throw the error in the title:

```
#call bamboo REST to get latest build number, save xml data as xml.txt
remote_file 'D:/git/chef/cookbooks/java-8-upgrade/xml.txt' do
  source 'http://REST-API-URL'
  #enter login credentials for bamboo
  headers( "Authorization"=>"Basic #{ Base64.encode64("username:password").gsub("\n", "") }" )
  action :create    
end

begin
file = File.open("D:/git/chef/cookbooks/java-8-upgrade/xml.txt", 'rb')
contents = file.read
end
```

What's strange is if I remove the last 4 lines entirely the xml.txt file is created fine, which makes me think that the remote_file call is asynchronous and somehow my begin-end block is being executed before the file has time to download.  Is there a way to wait until the file has downloaded before executing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for the full explanation, but tl;dr Chef runs in two passes and at the time that `File.open` runs, the `remote_file` resource has only be queued and not actually done anything yet. You don't give enough context here on what you're doing with the file data to say what the correct fix is, but some are outlined in my blog post.